# How to load a photosphere for panoramic extraction

Tags: import, uv-image-editor, panoramic

I'd like to import open a jpg photosphere in Blender exactly as someone does in Maya https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xzO9kXtIs04

Is that possible?

I'm new to Blender and having some problem in working with UI.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are in **Blender Internal**, here is the method used in the reference video.

1. Move your camera to (0, 0, 0).
2. Create a sphere <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Sphere*
3. Assign a material to the sphere and a texture to the material. Set the texture to image and load your image. Enable **Shadeless** on the material and set the texture's Mapping **Coordinates** to UV.
   [image]
4. Load the texture into the image editor. Go into edit mode of the sphere, select all vertices <kbd>A</kbd> and unwrap by pressing <kbd>U</kbd> > *Sphere Projection*.
   [image]
5. Set the viewports display mode to Textured <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> or Material. Go into camera view <kbd>Numpad0</kbd>. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to look around. (Camera fly mode.)
   [image]

Comment: At the 5th step I can't really look around as you show in the gif. When I press Shift + F it still navigates into the sphere

Comment: I am looking through the camera inside the sphere. Shift+F is just a method of rotating the camera by moving the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

You can import an HDRI and plot it in your "world object". Assuming you are under Cycles Render, you go to Node Editor, and add the node setup as the following image. Note that on "Environment texture" node, you open your HDRI panorama image, and need to set it to equirectangular (in case is equirectangular). By the end of the node setup, your HDRI image will appear surrounding your objects. Other way you can do this is, by adding a huge sphere, UV unwraping it to a sphere projection, apply the texture and give an emission node to the material. But adding nodes to the "World" is faster and easier.[image: node setup]

Comment: Thanks, I'm really new to Blender, how do I add the node setup? Looking at the help, does not really help at the moment...

Comment: you notice on the top right corner a small triangle, click and drag and you get a new window. On the bottom left of that new window, is a small button. If you click that button, you can change that window to the node editor (like I did on the image of the answer). Activate "Use Nodes" on the bottom panel of that window, activate material and activate the world button (on my image, these buttons are in the red rectangle area). To add the nodes, you can press Shift+A or there is an option on the bottom panel, called Add. Then you search those nodes in the list.

Comment: you can follow this simple tutorial, or similar ones: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8MYDuWn-PoA

Comment: or this one (a bit more advanced):https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_4IN4V1SM-A&feature=youtu.be